# rating is not saving in sharepoint document library

Tags: document-library, rating

I enabled ratings from the Document Library settings page and choose “Rating settings”. Once this setting is made a new column is added to my library .But after selecting a rating, it is not saving. please guide me how to save it and use it?

Answer (score 6):

There is a timer job that helps aggregate the results.  It is possible that the job isn't running.  Here is a blog post I previously wrote about enabling those jobs.

http://www.mikeoryszak.com/sharepoint/configuring-sharepoint-2010s-social-aggregation-jobs

Answer (score 0):

The rating isn't saved directly to the db. You have to enable at least the services described in the article http://codename-srini.blogspot.com/2010/04/how-to-use-rating-control-in-sharepoint.html

Answer (score 0):

It might be saving, but it might be taking a long time, since the timer job is not scheduled to run at shorter time intervals by default. Follow the post above from @MikeOryszak and you should be able to see it within the scheduled interval.